# How to generalise the import script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a query to generate a CSV file from the data in a Postgres Table.The script is working fine.

But i have a situation where i need to create separate files using the data from a different table.

So basically only the below hardcoded one change and rest code is same.Now the situation is i have to create separate scripts for all CSV's.

Is there a way i can have one script and only change this parameters.

I'm using Jenkins to automate the CSV file creation.

filePath = '/home/jenkins/data/'
fileName = 'data.csv'

```
import csv
import os
import psycopg2
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime
from utils.config import Configuration as Config
from utils.postgres_helper import get_connection
from utils.utils import get_global_config
# File path and name.
filePath = '/home/jenkins/data/'
fileName = 'data.csv'
# Database connection variable.
connect = None
# Check if the file path exists.
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    try:
        # Connect to database.
        connect = get_connection(get_global_config(), 'dwh')
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        # Confirm unsuccessful connection and stop program execution.
        print("Database connection unsuccessful.")
        quit()
    # Cursor to execute query.
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    # SQL to select data from the google feed table.
    sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM data"
    try:
        # Execute query.
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
        # Fetch the data returned.
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        # Extract the table headers.
        headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        # Open CSV file for writing.
        csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w', newline=''),
                             delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n',
                             quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, escapechar='\\')
        # Add the headers and data to the CSV file.
        csvFile.writerow(headers)
        csvFile.writerows(results)
        # Message stating export successful.
        print("Data export successful.")
        print('CSV Path : '+ filePath+fileName)
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        # Message stating export unsuccessful.
        print("Data export unsuccessful.")
        quit()
    finally:
        # Close database connection.
        connect.close()
else:
    # Message stating file path does not exist.
    print("File path does not exist.")
```

Comment: Take a look at argparse: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: [click](https://pypi.org/project/click/) is an option as well.

Comment: @BeChillerToo Is there an example, i'm new to this and didn't find how to use it.May be could you please show an example.

Comment: Well the tutorial already explains everything